# Do websockets work with any data source such as DB2?

Tags: database, websocket, db2

I'm starting to learn websockets and I would like to know if they'res supported by a database like DB2 (or some other data-source)

Say I have a Spring Boot application, that provides data to a UI as a service. Typically, I would run SQL SELECT statements every so seconds from the Java application. However, I want to have a stream of data in the table (or perhaps a stream of just the changes made to the table) similar to having an open websocket connection to a Kafka topic .

Is it possible to use something like a STOMP websocket to have a connection opened to a DB2 table where it will stay open and consistently pull data? Does the data-source have to support websockets in order for that to work?

Answer (score 0):

No they do not. RDBMS client-server protocols are more involved than just streaming a load of bytes for the client to interpret.

Having said that, database connections are *already* persistent, duplex, and stateful, and had been long before the WebSocket protocol was conceived.